# Build Mail Server on OpenShift send and receive email MX point to OpenShift

Tags: email, openshift, mail-server, mx-record

Do I able to build a Mail Server on OpenShift, that can send and receive email base on point MX record to OpenShift?

Answer (score 0):

You can send mail from OS, but it won't receive, since Openshift only allows 80 and 443 into your gear.